# Calculating rate or percentage over certain amount of operations without storing them

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have two types of actions that can be made by a user A and B. I need to calculate the percentage/rate that represents A actions from the last 100 actions made by the user, A or B.
I don't think it is necessary to store all actions in order to calculate that like:

```
lastActions = [ A, A, A, B, B, A, B, A, A, A, A, B, A, B ...];
```

And when new actions arrives, removes item in first position while adding the new one in last position.
I works BUT, I believe there is a better solution for this taking in count that I do not need the order or timeline in which actions are made, just percentage of A actions over total(last 100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the exact proportion, then there is no escaping needing to store the actions so that you know exactly when to forget them.

If an approximate answer is good enough, then you can use a simple exponentially weighted moving average.  For this you update it with:

```
 weighted_average = 0.99 * weighted_average + 0.01 * observation
```

This actually is only getting 63.39% of its weight from the first 100, 23.205% from the next, 8.49% from the next, and so on.

In general if you want something that looks kind of like like an average over the last `n` samples you'd use `(1 - 1/n)` and `(1/n)` in place of `0.99` and `0.01` respectively.

This average will start off with a bias that takes a few hundred observations to die away.  There are a couple of ways to correct that.  The simplest is to count observations and then:

```
w = max(1/observations, 1/n)
weighted_average = (1 - 1/w) * weighted_average + (1/w) * observation
```

This will compute an exact average of all observations for the first `n` times, and then switch to exponential weighting after that.

This technique is widely used in areas as far apart as the Unix load average, updating neural networks, and tracking various financial indicators on Wall St.

Comment: Looks nice, I will make some practical experiments on this and bring a feedback. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused about the variables that you exposed. What is "observations", "observation" and "n" exactly?

Comment: `observations` is how many observations you have had.  `observation` is the current value, eg 1 for a and 0 for b.  `n` is how many you want to average over, in your case 100.